# PHP + MySQL software

Tags: php, sql, windows, ide

Need your suggestion on php/mysql software. I develop PHP websites using Dreamweaver, I also have to use phpmyadmin, sql query editor (to work with database) and WinSCP (to upload/backup files over SFTP).

Could you suggest me please some software which contains all in one (PHP syntax highlighting, db connections and running sql queries, etc..)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find that multiple software tools targeted at specific tasks work better than one software tool targeted at a plethora of tasks.

Comment: I like to have all my development tools in one IDE and not have to switch between applications to do a plethora of tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) has PHP highlighting, code completition, db manager and ftp/sftp + xdebug (your next step:) ) support.

Comment: And is Netbeans is free (as in beer)!

Comment: +1 even though it is going to be the vote that moves your answer ahead of mine :P  Zend costs money, and if NetBeans can do everything Josh needs, then that's awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Try Eclipse.  Go here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ it is the third one down in the list (platforms on the right).  You can connect to DB's, have intelli-sense (code completion) and more all for FREE!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com)?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to spend as much as Zend Studio ($399 one year) try [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com). It is free and for $99 you get the Pro version with extra features like SFTP support.

There is a stand-alone version and an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm forced to use Windows, JEdit is my editor of choice. It has syntax highlighting for almost any language, FTP/SFTP remote editing, SQL plugins, code completion plugins, and so many others that I can't even begin to list them.

And, it's FOSS!

You can find the JEdit project at http://www.jedit.org

Answer (score 1):

Your question is correctly tagged - you need an Integrated Development Environment (IDE)! Dreamweaver wants to be one but unfortunately it isn't.

If you're on a Mac I highly recommend [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/).

For any platform; I've had a great experience with [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) (a fork of [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)) and these open-source IDEs are just bursting with useful plugins. Even Aptana's default project templates were useful instead of fluff!

One guy in my team loves [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) to bits.

Right now I'm addicted to shelling into the server and using command-line tools like `vi` or `nano`, `svn`, `mysql`. A steep (and important) learning curve but *everything* is possible on the command line. And with minimal client requirements. Do anything from anywhere!

I think the true answer is subjective - you'll need to dive in and try each one to see how they fit your working style.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite text editor: [e texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) which a clone of a mac app called [textmate](http://macromates.com/).

There is a lot of support for many languages, although Zend Studio will give you more "integration" features.